# get paragraph with awk, and start-of-line regexp

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, gawk

I use awk to get paragraphs from a textfile, like so:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/pattern/' ./textfile
```

Say I have the following textfile:

```
aaa bbb ccc
aaa bbb ccc
aaa bbb ccc

aaa ccc
bbb aaa ccc
bbb aaa ccc

ccc bbb aaa
ccc bbb aaa
ccc bbb aaa
```

Now I only want the paragraph with one of the (original) lines **starting** with "bbb" (hence the second paragraph). However - using regexp `^` will not work anymore, (I presume) because of the `RS=''` line; awk now only matches to the begin of the paragraph.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

`^` means start-of-string. You want start-of-line which is `(^|\n)`, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/(^|\n)bbb/' file
aaa ccc
bbb aaa ccc
bbb aaa ccc
```